# carousel doesn't show images. How can i make the carousel work on my web?

Tags: html

carousel doesn't show image
carousel doesn't show image
carousel doesn't show image
This web is powered by bootstrap.
carousel doesn't show image
carousel doesn't show image
carousel doesn't show image
carousel doesn't show image
carousel doesn't show image
carousel doesn't show image
carousel doesn't show image
carousel doesn't show image
carousel doesn't show image
carousel doesn't show image
carousel doesn't show image

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Gallary</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-lg">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="./home.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" title="Showing example of Carousel" href="./gallary.html">Gallery</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" title="Showing example of Grid system" href="./sampledata.html">Mountain Data</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>


        <div id="gallaryimages" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#gallaryimages" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#gallaryimages" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#gallaryimages" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/killington.jpg" alt="Killington Mountain">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h5>Killington Mountain</h5>
                        <p>4763 Killington Rd, VT</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/hunter.jpg" alt="Hunter Mountain">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h5>Hunter Mountain</h5>
                        <p>64 Klein Ave, NY</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/mountcreek.jpg" alt="Mount Creek"  data-rjs="3">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h5 style="color: red;">Mountain Creek</h5>
                        <p style="color:black;">123 NJ-94, NJ</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#gallaryimages" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#gallaryimages" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="text text-center">
            <a href="./sampledata.html" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Let's Move to stats page</a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="./js/retina/retina.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please, before ask a question, try to formulate your question, what you tried so far, so se can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to change the spelling gallary to gallery around lines 69 and 65 then you need to make sure the image names are well specified

```
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#galleryimages" role="button" data-slide="next">

<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#galleryimages" role="button" data-slide="prev">
```